# Python MySQL select JSON value as actual data type

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL connector in Python to store and get some JSON data. I'm having problem with getting the stored JSON value as actual Python data type. Hope someone could point me to the right direction.

Let's say I have the following table, TestTable;

```
id   data
1    {"val": 100.5}
2    {"val": true}
```

And I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id, data->"$.val" FROM TestTable;
```

1. When I run the query int the mysql client's terminal, the result looks good
2. When I run the query in a Python script, the results for "val" are of type string for the float value (ie. '100.5') and boolean for the bool value (ie. true)

This is the Python code

```py
cmd = "SELECT id, data->"$.val" FROM TestTable;"
mysql_cur.execute(cmd)
res = mysql_cur.fetchall()
mysql_cur.close()
# res has id and val. id is of type int, val is of type string for float value and type bool for boolean value
```

How do I get the result into Python's data type, ie. float and bool?

Thanks,

Comment: You can't.  In the resultst, all values in this column must have the same datatype.

Comment: @GMB Even if all the "val" are float values, the result set still has val as string.

Comment: then check the content and convert it

Comment: @nbk That's what I am doing right now.  I am hoping for a better way to do that, such as a setting I don't know about within the mysql connector to automatically convert them just as how the boolean values are converted.

Answer (score 1):

Json  is basically a string, so the result is also always string.

And that is what you are receiving, and no one can convert it automatically, because only, you decide what the bytes are meaning.

Save your data properly in rows and columns and not as json or any other delimited string

Comment: Actually, the boolean type is auto-converted in the result set so MySQL connector already has a way to deal with it. When I do `JSON_TYPE(data->"$.val"`), it shows the actual expected type (ie. "DOUBLE" and "BOOLEAN"). I'm just not sure why the double values were not automatically converted like the boolean values.

Comment: as GMb already said, you can't ,ix types,. so stay with your cobnversion in your code